# Count total work hours of the employee per date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the pandas dataframe like this:

```
Employee_id  timestamp
   1        2017-06-21 04:47:45
   1        2017-06-21 04:48:45
   1        2017-06-21 04:49:45
```

for each employee, I am getting ping every 1 minute if he/she is in the office.
I have around 2000 employee's ping, I need the output like:

```
Employee_id    date           Total_work_hour
     1      2018-06-21               8
     1      2018-06-22               7
     2      2018-06-21               6
     2      2018-06-22               8
```

for all 2000 employee

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with lambda function for [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) with `sum` of all diferences, then convert it to seconds by [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and divide by `3600` for hours:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['Employee_id', df['timestamp'].dt.date])['timestamp']
        .apply(lambda x: x.diff().sum())
        .dt.total_seconds()
        .div(3600)
        .reset_index(name='Total_work_hour'))
print (df1)
   Employee_id  timestamp  Total_work_hour
0            1 2017-06-21         0.033333
```

But if possible some missing consecutive minutes, is possible use custom function:

```
print (df)
   Employee_id           timestamp
0            1 2017-06-21 04:47:45
1            1 2017-06-21 04:48:45
2            1 2017-06-21 04:49:45
3            1 2017-06-21 04:55:45

def f(x):
    vals = x.diff()
    return vals.mask(vals > pd.Timedelta(60, unit='s')).sum()

df1 = (df.groupby(['Employee_id', df['timestamp'].dt.date])['timestamp']
        .apply(f)
        .dt.total_seconds()
        .div(3600)
        .reset_index(name='Total_work_hour')
        )
print (df1)
   Employee_id  timestamp  Total_work_hour
0            1 2017-06-21         0.033333
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I have posted for the first time